# PostgreSQL: How do you get the source columns of a materialized view?

Tags: sql, postgresql, materialized-views

I would like to get information on the columns of the materialized view such as the source tables and columns.

I created a materialized view called `student_teacher_mv` by joining the `student` and `teacher` tables as shown below.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW student_teacher_mv AS (
   SELECT 
      student.id AS student_id,
      student.name AS student_name,
      student.teacher_id as teacher_id,
      teacher.name as teacher_name
   FROM student
   JOIN teacher
      ON teacher.id = student.teacher_id
);
```

I have written this query which gives me information about the materialized view and its columns:

```
SELECT 
    pg_namespace.nspname AS mv_schema,
    pg_class.relname AS mv_name,
    pg_attribute.attname AS mv_col_name,
    pg_type.typname AS mv_col_type,
    pg_attribute.attnum AS mv_col_sort_order
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace
    ON pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attribute
    ON pg_class.oid = pg_attribute.attrelid
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_statio_all_tables st 
    ON pg_namespace.nspname = st.schemaname 
    AND pg_class.relname = st.relname
INNER JOIN pg_type
    ON pg_type.oid = pg_attribute.atttypid
WHERE pg_class.relkind = 'm'
    AND pg_attribute.attnum >= 1
    AND pg_class.relname = 'student_teacher_mv'
ORDER BY mv_schema, mv_name, mv_col_sort_order;
```

I have also written this query which gives me information about the materialized view and which tables, views and/or materialized views along with the columns it is derived from:

```
SELECT
    pg_namespace.nspname AS mv_schema,
    pg_rewrite.ev_class::regclass AS mv_name,
    pg_class.relname AS source_name,
    pg_attribute.attname AS source_col_name,
    pg_depend.refobjsubid AS source_col_sort_order
FROM pg_rewrite
JOIN pg_depend ON
    pg_depend.classid = 'pg_rewrite'::regclass AND
    pg_depend.objid = pg_rewrite.oid AND
    pg_depend.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass AND
    pg_depend.refobjid <> pg_rewrite.ev_class
JOIN pg_class ON
    pg_class.oid = pg_depend.refobjid AND
    pg_class.relkind IN ('r','v','m')
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace
    ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attribute
    ON pg_class.oid = pg_attribute.attrelid
    AND pg_attribute.attnum = pg_depend.refobjsubid
WHERE
  pg_rewrite.ev_class = 'student_teacher_mv'::regclass
```

Essentially I want to be able to combine the results of these two queries, but having a hard time figuring out how/what to join on. I can't seem to find any sort of identifier linking the new column to the derived ones.

Answer (score 0):

Something like (I have done a LEFT JOIN, but that should have been an INNER JOIN):

```
SELECT 
    pg_namespace.nspname AS mv_schema,
    pg_class.relname AS mv_name,
    pg_attribute.attname AS mv_col_name,
    pg_type.typname AS mv_col_type,
    pg_attribute.attnum AS mv_col_sort_order,
    x.source_name,
    x.source_col_name
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace
    ON pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attribute
    ON pg_class.oid = pg_attribute.attrelid
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_statio_all_tables st 
    ON pg_namespace.nspname = st.schemaname 
    AND pg_class.relname = st.relname
INNER JOIN pg_type
    ON pg_type.oid = pg_attribute.atttypid
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
    pg_namespace.nspname AS mv_schema,
    pg_rewrite.ev_class::regclass AS mv_name,
    pg_class.relname AS source_name,
    pg_attribute.attname AS source_col_name,
    pg_depend.refobjsubid AS source_col_sort_order
FROM pg_rewrite
JOIN pg_depend ON
    pg_depend.classid = 'pg_rewrite'::regclass AND
    pg_depend.objid = pg_rewrite.oid AND
    pg_depend.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass AND
    pg_depend.refobjid <> pg_rewrite.ev_class
JOIN pg_class ON
    pg_class.oid = pg_depend.refobjid AND
    pg_class.relkind IN ('r','v','m')
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace
    ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attribute
    ON pg_class.oid = pg_attribute.attrelid
    AND pg_attribute.attnum = pg_depend.refobjsubid
WHERE
  pg_rewrite.ev_class = 'student_teacher_mv'::regclass
) x On x.mv_schema = pg_namespace.nspname and source_col_sort_order=pg_attribute.attnum
WHERE pg_class.relkind = 'm'
    AND pg_attribute.attnum >= 1
    AND pg_class.relname = 'student_teacher_mv'
ORDER BY mv_schema, mv_name, mv_col_sort_order;
```

Comment: Hi Luuk, thanks for the answer but there is still an issue because the `pg_attribute.attnum` doesn't necessarily map to `source_col_sort_order`.

For instance, if the `student` table had 10 columns and the `teacher` table had 10 columns, each of the respective `source_col_sort_order` would go from 1-10 and if let's say I grabbed all 10 columns from both the source tables, I would have 20 columns in the materialized view and `pg_attribute.attnum` would go from 1-20.

So it would only match the first 10 columns from the materialized view twice to each column in both tables.

Comment: OK, but in my answer you can see how to JOIN those 2 queries, matching the columns is a job you can do much better, because you do have those tables from which you are creating a materialized view ...

Comment: I have the source tables, but I don't know what PostgreSQL System Catalog to use and how I can identify which column links to the new columns.

Comment: Luckily they (from postgresql) did do some documentation on their tables, like [pg_depend](https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgrespro/14/catalog-pg-depend)

Comment: Went through all the fields in `pg_depend` and none of them were useful in this case. Thanks for your help! :)